# My java socket program gives java.io.EOFException while running from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, eof

I am running a Java Socket client. It works if you run it first time or the first few times. However, after half day's debugging, the DataInputStream's readByte() method of reading the TCP socket will throw java.io.EOFException. If I reboot Eclipse, or run the same java code standalone, no problem at all. I guess, it has something to do with the way Eclipse run/debug the Java code. Somehow, some resources are used each time when we debug the program, and not released afterwards. Anybody knows?

Here is the code

```
//DataInputStream is set outside of the scope. 

DataInputStream dataInputStream; 

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while(true) 
{
    // java.io.EOFException is thrown at the line below. 
    byte c = dataInputStream.readByte();
    if( c == 0) {
         break;
    }
    stringBuffer.append( (char)c);
}
```

Comment: without any code that´s just plain guessing. You might want to add your code and the stacktrace in order to recieve an answer.

Comment: code snippet is added.

Comment: Maybe the other side time out and shutdown the socket.

Comment: No, it works well outside of Eclipse. Only after running inside of Eclipse for half day, it stops working unless you reboot Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

In general, it is not a good practice to `break` out of a `while(true)` (or even have a `while(true)` loop in the first place). Just because a byte==0 doesn't mean you have reached the end of a data stream. You should really check to see if there is more data that can be read from the stream instead of assuming a null byte (0 in Java) is read (using something like `available()`). A simple fix could look something along the lines of this:

```
DataInputStream dataInputStream; 

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while(dataInputStream.available() > 0) 
{
    byte c = dataInputStream.readByte();
    stringBuffer.append( (char)c);
}
```

This should continue to append characters to your StringBuffer, as well as stop when an EoF is reached.

Comment: This makes no sense because this part of the code do work usually, it only stops working while inside of Eclipse and after half day run.

Comment: @AlbertCheng Given the code that you have posted, this is the only solution I can think of. Your question does not explain much aside from you are having an EOF Exception, which this answer is attempting to solve.